# Detect scrolling in embedded PDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, scroll, rendering

On my page I have an embedded PDF file and I want to detect if the user scrolled at least once to make a continue button visible. I tried a few things the came to my mind, namely:

Putting the onscroll event into the HTML

```
<object data="flgs/EUW/EUW.pdf#zoom=38&toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&view=fit" 
type="application/pdf" width="60%" height="60%" onscroll="PDF()" style="position:relative; right:20%; left:20%;">
</object>
```

In JS

```
document.getElementById('PDF').addEventListener('scroll')

$('#PDF').on('scroll')

and $('#PDF').scroll()
```

All three of those are different examples I tried and not in the same script at once.
Is there a way I can detect whether the user scrolled in the PDF or not?

Comment: iirc embedded pdfs dont have bubbling events to the dom. You will not be able to use event listeners directly on the embed, however there are many libraries that can render pdfs and include it in the dom for event listeners.